# WSO2 Device management agent android not work for a box TV

Tags: mdm, android-tv, device-management, tvbox, wso2-iot

I used a WSO2 device management agent for box TV but it doesn't work.I can't synchronize with the wso2 iot server. The same agent work fine with my phone!! any ideas please. Thank you

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita for the moment I didn't use the code. I have just Installed the wso2 IoT server in my laptop and the wso2 device management agent in the box TV. I did the enrollment of the box in the server but I can't control the box (can't neither send messages from the server to the box, nor notifications nor install applications nor anything)!! I tested the same agent in my phone and it worked fine.